# Using Manufacturer's unmanaged code without calling it, but calling it your way

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, video

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace FlyCapture2Managed
{
public class ManagedImage : IDisposable
{
    public ManagedImage();
    public ManagedImage(ManagedImage image);
    public ManagedImage(byte* pData, uint dataSize);
    public ManagedImage(uint rows, uint cols, PixelFormat format);
    public ManagedImage(uint rows, uint cols, PixelFormat format, BayerTileFormat bayerFormat);
    public ManagedImage(uint rows, uint cols, uint stride, byte* pData, uint dataSize, PixelFormat format);
    public ManagedImage(uint rows, uint cols, uint stride, byte* pData, uint dataSize, PixelFormat format, BayerTileFormat bayerFormat);
    public ManagedImage(uint rows, uint cols, uint stride, byte* pData, uint dataSize, uint receivedActualSize, PixelFormat format);
    public ManagedImage(uint rows, uint cols, uint stride, byte* pData, uint dataSize, uint receivedActualSize, PixelFormat format, BayerTileFormat
  }
```

Thats the original code.
I am trying to get this done

```
 using System;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 namespace FlyCapture2Managed2
 {
  public struct ManagedImage2 : IDisposable
  {
public ManagedImage2();
public ManagedImage2(ManagedImage image);
public ManagedImage2(byte* pData, uint dataSize);
public ManagedImage2(uint rows, uint cols, PixelFormat format);
public ManagedImage2(uint rows, uint cols, PixelFormat format, BayerTileFormat bayerFormat);
public ManagedImage2(uint rows, uint cols, uint stride, byte* pData, uint dataSize, PixelFormat format);
public ManagedImage2(uint rows, uint cols, uint stride, byte* pData, uint dataSize, PixelFormat format, BayerTileFormat bayerFormat);
public ManagedImage2(uint rows, uint cols, uint stride, byte* pData, uint dataSize, uint receivedActualSize, PixelFormat format);
public ManagedImage2(uint rows, uint cols, uint stride, byte* pData, uint dataSize, uint receivedActualSize, PixelFormat format, BayerTileFormat
  }
  public class managed
    {
    [DllImport(@"S:\FlyCapture2SimpleGUI_CSharp\bin\x64\Debug\FlyCapture2Managedd_v100.dll",  CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

    static extern void managed();  
}
```

I keep getting the error on the errors

```
The type or namespace name 'PixelFormat' could not be found (are you missing a 
using directive or an assembly reference?). The Pixelformat in this case is part of the name space "flycapture" and not System.Drawing.imaging namepspace
```

However I don't want to use the reference as I would prefer referencing this bit of code in my work.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The `PixelFormat` enum is a part of the `System.Drawing.Imaging` namespace, so you should add this using directive at the top of your file:

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

Comment: The Pixelformat in this case is part of the namespace "flycapture" and not System.Drawing.imaging namepspace.

Comment: @user1462296: Then you should add a reference to the library containing the "flycapture" namespace and add `using flycapture;` at the top of your file.

Comment: I have the thing is when I do that the other bits of the program will use flycapture as reference and that i don't want to happen

Comment: @user1462296: Why don't you want that to happen?

Comment: i want to have alot of flexibility. And From what I have noticed without having it seperately it might not work

Comment: @user1462296: But if you don't add a reference, then you'll probably keep getting the error.